# Why do I get "Error 'configure:3485: error: C compiler cannot create executables'" when I install Ruby 1.9.3 on Fedora 12?

Tags: fedora, ruby

When trying to install Ruby 1.9.3 on Fedora 12, following "[Complete Guide to install Ruby 1.9.3 on CentOS](http://techblogthing.blogspot.com/2012/11/complete-guide-to-install-ruby-193-on.html)", I get the following error when running the command `./configure`:

```
$ ./configure 
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/ruby-1.9.3-p194':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Here is the [content of the config.log](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5380443).

I tried running both as root and non-root. I have permissions in the directory where I try to install, and used yum to install the following packages:

```
httpd-devel
openssl-devel
zlib-devel
gcc
gcc-c++
curl-devel
expat-devel
gettext-devel
patch
readline
readline-devel
zlib
zlib-devel
libyaml-devel
libffi-devel
make
bzip2
zlib1g
mysql-server
```

and did `yum groupinstall "Development tools"`

Comment: Why on earth are you trying to use such an old and unsupported distribution?

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that is curious are these lines in your log:

```
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.3/../../../crt1.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.3/../../../crti.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.3/../../../crtn.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
```

It looks like you've got a mismatch between 32-bit and 64-bit code.